# convert 1 field of awk to base64 and leave the rest intact

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm creating a one liner where my ldap export is directly converted into a csv. 
So far so good but the challange is now that 1 column of my csv needs to contain base64 encoded values. These values are comming as clear text out of the ldap search filter. So I basically need them converted during the awk creation.

What I have is:

```
ldapsearch | awk -v OFS=',' '{split($0,a,": ")}  /^blobinfo:/{blob=a[2]} /^cn:/{serialnr=a[2]} {^mode=a[2]; print serialnr, mode, blob}'
```

This gives me a csv output as intended but now I need to convert blob to base64 encoded output.

Getline is not available

demo input:

```
cn: 1313131313
blobinfo: a string with spaces
mode: d121

cn: 131313asdf1313
blobinfo: an other string with spaces
mode: d122
```

ouput must be like

```
1313131313,D121,YSBzdHJpbmcgd2l0aCBzcGFjZXM=
```

where **YSBzdHJpbmcgd2l0aCBzcGFjZXM=** is the encoded **a string with spaces**

but now I get

```
1313131313,D121,a string with spaces
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: I'd use perl instead of awk, as it comes with a module for encoding values in base 64. But, yeah, need sample data to use to come up with a working version.

Comment: updated, perl is available on the system

Comment: Please put inputs and outputs in code blocks - prepend the inputs with 4 spaces. It's unreadable as it is now. Do you have `base64` utility from coreutils? Then it's just passing the sting to `base64` and placing the result back.

Comment: What is the use of converting a string to base64, which will be an inefficient (in terms of space) representation of the same data again as a string?

Comment: That awk code you posted has a syntax error and I can't see how it could produce the output you give, btw - you assign every variable the same value `a[2]`?

Comment: We need to export it from program A to program B. Program B however requires that this string is base64 encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -lne '
   BEGIN { $, = "," }
   if (/^cn: (.+)/) { $s = $1 }
   if (/^blobinfo: (.+)/) { $b = encode_base64($1, "") }
   if (/^mode: (.+)/) { print $s, $1, $b }' input.txt
1313131313,d121,YSBzdHJpbmcgd2l0aCBzcGFjZXM=
131313asdf1313,d122,YW4gb3RoZXIgc3RyaW5nIHdpdGggc3BhY2Vz
```

Comment: I updated the ticket again, by posting the info everything was send to 1 line. ldap search is actually returning blocks

Comment: @YannickDeBacker Getting your sample data right the first time would save a lot of trouble.

Comment: I konw, sorry :/

Comment: is it possible that perl has a limited output of character / line, my encoded string is apearing on 4 lines

Comment: Normally base64 strings get line wrapped at 76 characters. Try passing an empty string as a second argument to `encode_base64()` and see if that changes it.

Comment: solved it with the empty string as second argument. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `getline` and you just need to output the csv (you can't further process the base64'd field), change the order of fields in output and abuse the `system`'s newline. First, a bit modified input data (changed order, missing field):

```
cn: 1313131313
blobinfo: a string with spaces
mode: d121

blobinfo: an other string with spaces
mode: d122
cn: 131313asdf1313

cn: 131313asdf1313
mode: d122
```

The awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    RS=""                            # read in a block of rows
    FS="\n"                          # newline is the FS
    h["cn"]=1                        # each key has a fixed buffer slot
    h["blobinfo"]=2
    h["mode"]=3
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {             # for all fields
        split($i,a,": ")             # split to a array
        b[h[a[1]]]=a[2]              # store to b uffer
    }
    printf "%s,%s,",b[1],b[3]        # output all but blob, no newline
    system("echo " b[2] "| base64")  # let system output the newline
    delete b                         # buffer needs to be reset
}' file                              # well, I used file for testing, you can pipe
```

ANd the output:

```
1313131313,d121,YSBzdHJpbmcgd2l0aCBzcGFjZXMK
131313asdf1313,d122,YW4gb3RoZXIgc3RyaW5nIHdpdGggc3BhY2VzCg==
131313asdf1313,d122,Cg==
```

Comment: Only 1 small problem here, I'm not 100% sure that the input will always in the same order.

Comment: Well, that's no problem. You can order the output with the key. The idea was to show how to output with `system`.

Comment: @YannickDeBacker Updated with the surprise requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code also solved it. Nice code